# How find this sum $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+2j}{m}t^{2j},0<t<1$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $m$ is give postive integer numbers,

Find the sum
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+2j}{m}t^{2j},0<t<1$$

if this not have closed form,and can you use Special function ?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28binomial%28k%2B2*r%2Ck%29a%5E%282*r%29%2Cr%3D0...infinity%29

Answer (score 5):

Since, for $-1<t<1$, we have 
$$\eqalign{
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{m+k}{m}t^k&=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(m+k)\cdots (k+1)}{m!}t^k
=\frac{1}{m!}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty t^{k+m}\right)^{(m)}\cr
&=\frac{1}{m!}\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)^{(m)}=\frac{1}{(1-t)^{m+1}}
}$$
we conclude that 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{m+k}{m}t^k+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{m+k}{m}(-t)^k=\frac{1}{(1-t)^{m+1}}+\frac{1}{(1+t)^{m+1}}
$$
or
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{m+2j}{m}t^{2j}=\frac{1}{2(1-t)^{m+1}}+\frac{1}{2(1+t)^{m+1}}
$$